# Different layer.name() in batchmode in QGIS processing script

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

Different `layer.name()` in single layer processing and batchmode in QGIS scripts.

QGIS version 3.10.7.

```
My example script:
```

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
***************************************************************************
*                                                                         *
*   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
*   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
*   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
*   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
*                                                                         *
***************************************************************************
"""

from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)
from qgis import processing


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
   
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

    def tr(self, string):
        """
        Returns a translatable string with the self.tr() function.
        """
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

    def name(self):
        return 'myscript'

    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('My Script')

    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Example scripts')

    def groupId(self):
        return 'examplescripts'

    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example algorithm short description")

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
       
        feedback.pushInfo(parameters['INPUT'])

        source = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )

        if source is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.INPUT))

        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
            parameters,
            self.OUTPUT,
            context,
            source.fields(),
            source.wkbType(),
            source.sourceCrs()
        )

        # Send some information to the user
        feedback.pushInfo('CRS is {}'.format(source.sourceCrs().authid()))
   

        if sink is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSinkError(parameters, self.OUTPUT))

        # Compute the number of steps to display within the progress bar and
        # get features from source
        total = 100.0 / source.featureCount() if source.featureCount() else 0
        features = source.getFeatures()

        for current, feature in enumerate(features):
            # Stop the algorithm if cancel button has been clicked
            if feedback.isCanceled():
                break

            # Add a feature in the sink
            sink.addFeature(feature, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)

            # Update the progress bar
            feedback.setProgress(int(current * total))

        if False:
            buffered_layer = processing.run("native:buffer", {
                'INPUT': dest_id,
                'DISTANCE': 1.5,
                'SEGMENTS': 5,
                'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
                'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
                'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
                'DISSOLVE': False,
                'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
            }, context=context, feedback=feedback)['OUTPUT']

        return {self.OUTPUT: dest_id}
```

Outputs from single mode:

```
QGIS verze: 3.10.13-A Coruna
QGIS revize kódu: 311f3bbade
Qt verze: 5.11.2
GDAL verze: 3.1.4
GEOS verze: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ verze: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Zpracovávám algoritmus...
Algoritmus 'My Script' se spouští…
Vstupní parametry:
{ 'INPUT' : 'G:/work/weird_layer_name/wl/layers/example.gpkg|layername=example', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT' }

example_82da6a66_eea8_4ad9_8b94_f7fbd945449f
CRS is EPSG:4326
Spuštění dokončeno za 0.10 sekund
Výsledky:
{'OUTPUT': 'Output_layer_076e3e5f_5400_409b_9e59_9224f5be8e15'}

Načítám výsledné vrstvy
Algoritmus 'My Script' dokončen
```

**Layer.name() = example_82da6a66_eea8_4ad9_8b94_f7fbd945449f**

Outputs from batchmode:

```
Zpracovávám algoritmus 1/2...
Algoritmus My Script se spouští…
Vstupní parametry:
{'INPUT': 'example',
'OUTPUT': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':G:/work/weird_layer_name/wl/layers/result1.gpkg, 'createOptions': {}}>}

example
CRS is EPSG:4326
Algoritmus My Script v poøádku spuštìn...
Execution completed in 2.04 seconds
Výsledky:
{'OUTPUT': 'G:/work/weird_layer_name/wl/layers/result1.gpkg'}

Naèítám výsledné vrstvy

Zpracovávám algoritmus 2/2...
Algoritmus My Script se spouští…
Vstupní parametry:
{'INPUT': 'Output layer',
'OUTPUT': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':G:/work/weird_layer_name/wl/layers/result2.gpkg, 'createOptions': {}}>}

Output layer
CRS is EPSG:4326
Algoritmus My Script v poøádku spuštìn...
Execution completed in 0.28 seconds
Výsledky:
{'OUTPUT': 'G:/work/weird_layer_name/wl/layers/result2.gpkg'}

Naèítám výsledné vrstvy
Batch execution completed in 2.40 seconds
```

**Layer.name() = example**

Different between batch and single mode is `example_82da6a66_eea8_4ad9_8b94_f7fbd945449f` (single) and `example` (batchmode).

**Is this different bug or true result?**

In QGIS version 3.16 are layer.name() equal.